# *ngFor not working in Angular

Tags: angular

Trying to retrieve data from firebase using Angular.
I have some data stored in Firebase and I want o show the data stored in third child.
Here is how my firebase look.
[check this image screenshot of Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSGuR.png)

my component code is

```
this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
if(this.id) {this.scheduleService.get(this.id).take(1).subscribe(p =>    this.date =p);}
```

My Service code is below

```
getDates(){
    return this.db.list('date').snapshotChanges().map(action => {
      return action.map(
        item => {
          const $key = item.payload.key;
          const data = { $key, ...item.payload.val() };
          return data;
      });
    });
  }
```

And here is HTML code to show the data.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of date.artist1.avlTime">
  <li>
  {{item?.fromtimeAm}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Tried different html type to get that third/fourth child data but nothing is working.

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase, but you definitely have another layer to go through after `avlTime` before accessing the element (that string starting with `-La`, not sure whether that's an array or an object).

Comment: looks like fromtimeAm is not on avlTime but on the first child. Wouldn't  <ul *ngFor="let item of Object.values(date.artist1.avlTime)[0]  or something like that work?

Comment: If you put `<pre>{{ item | json }}</pre>` in your template right there you'd be able to see what your data looks like. You'd help yourself out a ton if you created interfaces that match up with your data in the data store.

Comment: alv time does not look like an array

Comment: You keep saying it isn't working but you don't explain what that means. What errors are you receiving? Or do you see a blank screen? Be specific

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for support.
I fixed the issue.
I created new function in service.

```
getAvlDate(id){
    return this.db.list('date/'+id+'/artist1/avlTime').snapshotChanges().map(action => {
      return action.map(
        item => {
          const $key = item.payload.key;
          const data = { $key, ...item.payload.val() };
          return data;
      });
    });
  }
```

then added this code to component TS file

```
this.scheduleService.getAvlDate(this.id).take(1).subscribe(p=>this.availableTime =p);
```

and then in HTML following code worked to retrieve the data.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of availableTime">
                  <li>
                    {{item.fromtimeHr}}{{item.fromtimeMn}} {{item.fromtimeAm}}
                  </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes angular doesn't recognize arrays/lists as something that can be cycled through in an ngFor. Try calling a function in yout .ts file that returns the list like this:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of getAvlTime()">
  <li>
  {{item?.fromtimeAm}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

.ts file:

```
getAvlTime() {
   if (this.date != undefined && this.date.artist1 != undefined) {
      return this.date.artist1.avlTime as any[];
   } else {
      return [];
   }
}
```

Comment: -1 for `as any[]`, which does nothing to resolve the issue but would reduce code quality, and for using `getX() {}` over `get x() {}`

Comment: It doesn't matter that I didn't post a solution since you posted so crappy advice that isn't a solution. I meant you should use a property with a get accessor for such code is that if a method with a prefix. What is this Java?

Comment: That would be a waste of time, you don't need to add a property. He's just got a component that isn't recognizing a list as a list. Simply calling a function in the typescript file of the component to return an array fixes the issue. Using as any[] forces it to be recognized as an array and fixes it

Comment: Why would you down-vote an answer that works? If you think it's not the best solution, then post another solution that also works, and the user will check-mark the one that they like best

Comment: That's ridiculous. He doesn't say what there is, so why do you think it's a compile error? Even if it is, the app is running because such errors are just warnings in typescript. As regards to using a property, how is it any more unnecessary than writing a getX method? My point  about the property was that your style is bad. it still doesn't change that you aren't solving the problem because you don't even know what it is.

Comment: I have had this exact issue before and the solution I posted fixed it. The ngFor is not cycling through the list because it doesn't think it is a list. I did not say it is a compiler error, there is no error. The ngFor just doesn't cycle through because it doesn't think there is any list to cycle through

Comment: TypeScript type information isn't available at runtime

Comment: it doesn't work for the OP because you don't know what the error is and therefore can't say. As for your own experience, your code doesn't work _because_ of the type assertion. It's not only possible, but actually rather common, especially since type declarations are so often poorly chosen, to pass values with arbitrary compile time types to `ngFor`. You made two changes and credited the wrong one. Try it

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for the help. I tried your solution. Created same function in ts file as per your solution and called ngFor as given in solution. But it did not work for me. It shows blank result. The error in console is "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'artist1' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]" I think we are close to solution.

Comment: I think it's calling the getAvlTime() function before this.date is being set, so the javascript is breaking before the data comes in. I've updated my solution to check for undefined before accessing that property, try that